# CSS + putting text into a input type=text

Tags: html, css

I have the following code and it works fine in all browsers:

```
 <input type="text" id="fileUploadTextBox" value="Browse My Computer"/>
```

When it comes to IE I wanted to change the text slightly to

```
 <input type="text" id="fileUploadTextBox" value="Browse My Computer (Double Click)"/>
```

Can I do this using CSS? I know how to run a separate CSS file for IE.

Or is there another way to do this?

thx

Comment: I think do that only with CSS inpossible
You can use that jQuery code

if ($.browser.msie) {
    $('#fileUploadTextBox').val('Browse My Computer (Double Click)')
}

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with CSS??

Comment: ok... understand... I thought it might be possible... thankyou for taking the time to explain this to me... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using [**conditional comments**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can do this:

**For Other Browsers:**

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <input type="text" id="fileUploadTextBox" value="Browse My Computer"/>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

**For IE Browsers:**

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <input type="text" id="fileUploadTextBox" value="Browse My Computer (Double Click)"/>
<![endif]-->
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/V2RtS/)

Or you can use Javascript/jQuery to achieve it.

Comment: perfect - thankyou... will tick the tick with the time limit passes... thx again!

Answer (score -1):

This Javascript with jQuery should work:

```
if ( $.browser.msie ) {
  <input type="text" id="fileUploadTextBox" value="Browse My Computer (Double Click)"/>
} else {
  <input type="text" id="fileUploadTextBox" value="Browse My Computer"/>
}
```